# Vue JS 2: Остановка жизненного цикла после beforeCreate

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Задача состоит в том, что бы в методе beforeCreate остановить рендеринг и выполнение created() и mounted(). Просто вызов $destroy() у компонента сработает после created.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: расскажите о том, что предшествовало задаче, и какова ее конечная цель

Comment: Цель в создании middleware, который может работать с vuex. Middleware в vue-router не подходят, так как они отрабатывают до наполнения vuex данными.

Comment: А чем не подходит создание пустого инстанса? Ну как eventBus = new Vue({});

Comment: @УстьянцевБорис а причем тут eventBus? Как это можно использовать? Прошу, если не затруднит, прикрепите пример.

Comment: не нашли ли ответ? я много искал, но ответа на этот вопрос нет. но он так же у меня появился. теоретически должен быть механизм прекращения. просто возврат false не помогает.

Comment: @romanown решения все еще нет.

Comment: спасибо. я сделал this.$options.template = null;
this.$options.el = null; чтобы не показывало ошибку из-за отсутствия элементов в разметке. это конечно не остановка поэтому когда вынес это в ответ, мне рекомендовали удалить, поскольку не является ответом на  вопрос.